# Highchart Maps (Highmaps)- data

Tags: highcharts, maps

http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-drilldown

In High chart Maps, I can click on state and all counties I can see. I want to click on county and see all zip codes within the county. Now the data for county is something like this

`{ "id": "US.WI.069", "name": "Lincoln", "path": "M 441.2,105.3 L 441.6,111.1 L 434.2,111.6     L 433.9,107.9 L 433.9,107.2 L 433.7,104.3 L 441.0,103.8 Z" } if i can get path information(viz "path": "M 441.2,105.3 L 441.6,111.1 L 434.2,111.6 L 433.9,107.9 L 433.9,107.2 L 433.7,104.3 L 441.0,103.8 Z")` for all zip codes in united states it will do the job. Would anyone know where I can find data for "path"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this information in the json, and then catch click event (to display it) or update tooltip formatter where this information will be extracted.

Comment: true I can do this but from where can i get this path info--> M 441.2,105.3 L 441.6,111.1 L 434.2,111.6     L 433.9,107.9 L 433.9,107.2 L 433.7,104.3 L 441.0,103.8 Z"    for all zip codes in united states

Comment: Could you explain what you mean, because it is not clear for me.

Comment: sure on this link http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-drilldown i can click on states and go to see what counties are there in that state.  I want to click on county and see map of all "ZIP CODES" inside that county. So all these shapes of states and counties are done by "path" which is like "M 441.2,105.3 L 441.6,111.1 L 434.2,111.6     L 433.9,107.9 L 433.9,107.2 L 433.7,104.3 L 441.0,103.8 Z"    if I can get hold of path like these for all zip codes in united states I will be able to do this. Unless if you can suggest something else with example

Comment: I prepared very simple example with single zipCode in JSON. To see this click on VA state and you will see that. If you add zip code for each element (in json) then will be displayed on the map.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2hj2/

Comment: Hi Sebastian I emailed you the question. there are many zip codes in one county and i want to show map structure similar to county map of state.

Comment: Have you found a good way to do this?  I want the same functionality. I do know you have to provide your own map for the zipcode level because HighMaps only goes down to the county level right now.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this ?